# Silverlight ComboBox popup alignment/weighting

Tags: silverlight, combobox, resize, popup

I've currently got an issue where I'm trying to keep the popup of a Silverlight combobox aligned to the combobox when they popup hits the edges of the browser on re-sizing.

By default once the combobox's popup hits the edges it shifts along with the edge of the browser window, but leaving the combobox behind. 
I've tried resizing the popup as well, but eventually it will shift.

I want to make sure the left of the popup is always in line with the left of combobox, and not have it shift after re-sizing the window.

Been looking and can only find people talking about flowdirection, this isn't what I'm looking for.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.